# "do .. while doing" or "do while do"

Tags: grammar

Here is a quick question. In the following two sentences, which one is correct?

```
XXX changes the syntax of software while keeping the semantic equivalence.

XXX changes the syntax of software while keeps the semantic equivalence.
```

Answer (score 2):

To make it more general: here the conjunction **while** is used to connect the main clause and the **participle construction**, which functions as an adverb in the provided example. In this case you should use present participle *keeping* after the conjunction while. In the main clause you have a subject (xxx or Bob), so you can use present simple tense *changes*. The examples in Grumble Snatch’s post illustrate this well:

> Bob changes the syntax of software while maintaining semantic equivalence.
>
> Bob maintains semantic equivalence while changing the syntax of software.

Alternatively, if you would like to use a finite verb both times (a finite verb must normally have a subject and a tense) you can use a compound sentence, for example:

> **Xxx changes** the syntax of software *and* **he/she/it keeps** the semantic equivalence.

Comment: Just wondering whether you're suggesting that the repetition of the subject is required in such a construction. "Xxx changes the syntax of software and keeps the semantic equivalence" seems perfectly OK to me.

Comment: @Rodney Honestly, I'm not sure I remember what I was suggesting a year and a half ago :-). To my (non-native-speaker's) ear your sentence sounds perfectly fine. On the other hand "XXX changes the syntax of software while keeps the semantic equivalence" makes me cringe. I'd say that with *while* you need to repeat the subject. Now, why did I write an example where I both repeated the subject **and** changed the conjunction - beats me. If I remember, I'll get back to you...

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Xxx changes the syntax of software **while keeping the semantic equivalence**.
> 2. Xxx changes the syntax of software **while keeps the semantic equivalence**. (wrong)

We can omit the subject of a subordinate clause that's headed by a so-called subordinating conjunction such as *while*. However, English usually only allows tensed verbs when the subject of the clause is overtly stated. Because the subject of *KEEP* is not represented in the subordinate clause in example (2), we cannot have a present tense form, *keeps*. In contrast in example (1), there is no subject, but we have a non-tensed gerund-participle form *keeping*, so this is fine.

We could, alternatively, reiterate the subject in the subordinate clause and therefore use the present tense form *keeps*:

- Xxx changes the syntax of software **while it keeps the semantic equivalence**.

This sentence might sound slightly better with the subordinate phrase occurring first:

- While it keeps the semantic equivalence, Xxx changes the syntax of software.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bob changes the syntax of software while maintaining semantic equivalence.
```

or

```
Bob maintains semantic equivalence while changing the syntax of software.
```

These options are both correct.

Answer (score 1):

"Changes the syntax of software" is a meaningless clause to this programmer.

Perhaps Bob rewrites the software (into the Ralph language) while maintaining semantic equivalence with the original (Joe language) version?